# How much seawater could be desalinated using the waste heat from a powerplant?

Tags: civil-engineering

I've done some rough calculations on how much water could be produced by using the waste heat of a powerplant to boil seawater.

I'm interested in a ballpark figure and would like to know if I have a major flaw in the calculations.

A 1MW plant with 1/3 efficiency can boil 17 moles of water per second assuming that the water is at the BP and it takes 40KJ/mol to boil it.

17 moles of water is 300g.

In one day the plant boils 26 tons of water.

One acre foot is around 1200 tons.

California uses 110,000 acre feet per day.  This is 132,000,000 tons per day.

This could be produced by 5,100,000MW.

It seems like this potential source would be a drop in the bucket in terms of meeting water needs.

Comment: You can recover much of the latent heat by condensing the clean steam using some inlet water that’s at a lower temperature

Comment: You've neglected the performance ratio achieved through running a multistage reverse flow MSD. PR's of 5 are achievable by third world operators. PRs of 15 are predicted using multi-effect distillation processes and really meticulous maintenance and operation. [OT-MSD](https://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/110611)

Comment: Another excellent reference. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233236572_Modelling_and_optimization_of_a_multistage_flash_desalination_process

Comment: Also check out Vapour Compression Distillation